# Imaginary part of refractive index = absorption or extinction?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I know that the imaginary part of the complex refractive index results in a damping of the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave. I wonder if this is because of absorption alone or comprising scattering of photons out of the beam as well, which in the case of exponential laws (Beer-Lambert) is known as extinction coefficient (absorption + losses due to scattering out of the beam)?

And if the imaginary part of the refractive index does not account for scattering, but describes only absorption... what is then describing scattering? The real part of the refractive index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refractive index doesn't describe scattering at all. The real part indicates deflection of an incident ray after transmission, while the imaginary part describes extinction due to absorption.

Scattering is a large problem that has a bunch of input parameters like e.g. size distribution of scatterers, their (complex) refractive indices. Sometimes also shapes and orientations of scatterers are significant (e.g. when describing [halos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(optical_phenomenon))).

There's no such thing as a refractive index that would by itself characterize extinction due to scattering. What does characterize relation between extinction and absorption of a medium is [single scattering albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-scattering_albedo).

Comment: Many thanks, but I'm a bit confused. In the first paragraph you say the refractive index doesn't describe scattering at all, but in the second paragraph you explucitly mention that I need the complex refractive index for scattering...?

Comment: In the second paragraph refractive index describes each scatterer (water drop, dust particle etc.). Each of these particles has its own refractive index (sometimes even varying across the particle). Scattering is the result of light passing through a medium containing these particles. There's no such thing as a refractive index that would by itself characterize extinction due to scattering.

Comment: Ok, then the answer is, the imaginary part of the refractive index is absorption only, correct?

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 Yes.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 the parameter you might be interested in is [single scattering albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-scattering_albedo). It does tell the relation between extinction and absorption of a medium.

Answer (score 1):

An answer only for the first part of your question:

It's absorption. You can see it more clearly in Poynting's theorem, where you can relate the fact that the refractive index has an imaginary part with the fact that $\vec{\jmath}.\vec{E}$ has a non-zero mean value. This describes an energy transfer from the fields to matter.

Comment: But extinction is absorption and scattering, and energy transfer means absorption only...

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the words. I meant absorption.